# Is there a known nextJS 13 rendering bug when rendering a component to layout.tsx?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, react-typescript, next.js13

I was creating a component, `<GlobalNav />` to import to layout.tsx, but it wasn't rendering correctly.
Here's a code of said navbar (global-nav.tsx):

```
'use client';

import Link from "next/link";
import { useSelectedLayoutSegment } from 'next/navigation';
import { useState } from 'react';

export function GlobalNav() {

  return (
    <div className="fixed top-0 z-10 flex w-full flex-col border-b border-gray-800 font-semibold bg-blue-600 lg:bottom-0 lg:z-auto lg:w-72 lg:border-b-0 lg:border-r lg:border-gray-800">
    test123
  </div>
  );
}
```

The only thing that correctly rendered was the text inside the div tags.

However when I copied that div and pasted directly inside layout.tsx instead of using it as a component like `<GlobalNav />`, it renders correctly.

```
import './globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import { GlobalNav } from '../ui/global-nav'
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang='en' className='bg-gray-400'>
      <body className='overflow-y-scroll bg-white pb-36'>
      {/* <GlobalNav /> */}
        <div className="fixed top-0 z-10 flex w-full flex-col border-b border-gray-800 font-semibold bg-blue-600 lg:bottom-0 lg:z-auto lg:w-72 lg:border-b-0 lg:border-r lg:border-gray-800">
    test123
        </div>

        <div className='lg:pl-72'>
          <div className='mx-auto max-w-4xl space-y-8 bg-blue-500 px-2 pt-20 lg:px-8 lg:py-8'>
            
            <div className='bg-vc-border-gradient rounded-lg p-px shadow-lg shadow-black/20'>
              <div className='rounded-lg bg-black'>
                {/* <AddressBar /> */}
                <div className='p-2 bg-white rounded-lg'></div> {/* temp dummy for address bar */}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className='bg-vc-border-gradient rounded-lg p-px shadow-lg shadow-black/20'>
              <div className='rounded-lg bg-black p-3.5 lg:p-6'>{children}</div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

I was wondering why this was occurring and if this was a bug of sorts.

Comment: Consider checking the file that contains `GlobalNav` is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration.

Comment: That solved it, thanks! I wasn't using the default `./components/..,` in the `content` file globs and included a new filepath.